# How puppeteer takes variable from window scope

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I want to get an object from window scope using the evaluate function. This is my code.

This is the variable in window scope.

```
let testCase = JSON.stringify({foo: bar});
```

This is the puppeteer code that I use to get the value from testCase variable.

```
console.log(await page.evaluate(() => testCase));
```

Output:

```
undefined
```

I know that puppeteer's evaluate function arguments must be serialized that's why I use Json.stringify(), but still doesn't work!

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try `window.testCase = ...` and `page.evaluate(() => window.testCase)`?

Comment: @MarkoGrešak I just tried but nothing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is highly recommended to watch for errors when debugging headless scripts — making screenshots, waiting for a necessary element to appear and also catching js errors from the page context, like this:

```
page.on('pageerror', err => console.log(err));
```

With this callback in place it becomes clear why the resutls is `undefined`:

> [Error: ReferenceError: bar is not defined

It seems that the `bar` variable is not defined on the target page, so assignment to `testCase` cannot be made, therefore it stays undefined.

Or if you're sure that `bar` is indeed defined, maybe it's created *later* in page's lifetime, *after* you're doing `page.evaluate`. In this case you'd want to use [page.waitFor](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args) to wait for it:

```
await page.goto(url)
await page.waitFor(() => typeof(testCase) !== "undefined") // <== WAITING
console.log(await page.evaluate(() => testCase));
```